# matplotlib animation in zeppelin

Tags: python, matplotlib, apache-zeppelin

I am a beginner in zeppelin. 
I would like to plot a dynamic plot which can auto update the graph when the new data is added. 
I tried to import matplotlib.animation in zeppelin, it didn't work. 
But it can work in Spyder and jupyter.
Does anyone can help me please?

[image]

Comment: Could you describe your problem here, without linking to external sites?

Comment: I think you are jumping some steps here. First, are you sure the Zeppelin backend can render animations at all?